# Scan and find the keywords in the database from the csv file, then calculate the occurrence rate of other words

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I need to find the presence rate/prevalence of words in a csv file separated by comma, for words next to a certain keyword on the line.

```
import pandas as pd
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")

searchDB = pd.read_csv('')
searchDB = searchDB["AllKeywords"].str.split(', ')
searchDB = searchDB.explode()

df = pd.read_csv('') // keywords to look for

for i in range(len(df)):
    keywordToSearch = df.loc[i, "H"]
    res = es.search(index=searchDB["AllKeywords"], body={"from":0, "size":0, "query":{"match":{"sentence": df.loc[i, "H"]}}})
```

I am getting an error on the last lines I'm using Elasticsearch. Can you help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects/DataImp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3629, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 41, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'AllKeywords'
```

Comment: Error is saying `searchDB["AllKeywords"]` does not exist because you overwrote `searchDB = searchDB.explode()`

Comment: There is a column named AllKewords in the csv file

Comment: Then you should be using `df['AllKeywords']` instead

Comment: Not really clear what your CSV file looks like, but do you really have commas within one column of a CSV? Are those values quoted? Do you really need `pandas` to read that file instead of `csv.DictReader`?

Comment: How can I write without overwriting?

Comment: How about `exploded = searchDB.explode()` instead? Rename the variable in the line before as `keywords`... And remove `df` since it seems to be the exact same as the original `searchDB`

Comment: There is an array on each row so its not in a dictionary form. I went over pandas because it looks more like a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your error is at `index=searchDB["AllKeywords"]`

Clean up your variables

```
import pandas as pd
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")

df = pd.read_csv('')
keywords = df["AllKeywords"].str.split(', ')
exploded_keywords = searchDB.explode()

for i in range(len(df)):
    keywordToSearch = df.loc[i, "H"]
    res = es.search(index=df["AllKeywords"], body={"from":0, "size":0, "query":{"match":{"sentence": keywordToSearch}}})
```